# django: subclass FormView twice and override form_class

Tags: python, django, django-forms, subclass, formview

Im trying to build a FormView for an app that needs to be subclassed afterwards. Sadly I was not able to set the formclass by the subclass.

My Code:

```
class EventCreateView(FormView):
    template_name='Events/add_event_form.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('events_list')
    form_class = None  # replaced by __init__ function

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.form_class=EventForm
        return super(EventCreateView, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    #other functions, not shown here .. 


class TrainingCreateView(EventCreateView):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.form_class=TrainingForm
        return super(TrainingCreateView, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

urls.py:

```
 urlpatterns = patterns('',
     url(r'event/event/add/$', EventCreateView.as_view(), name='event_add'),
     url(r'event/training/add/$', TrainingCreateView.as_view(), name='training_add'),
 )
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
class EventCreateView(FormView):
    template_name='Events/add_event_form.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('events_list')
    form_class = EventForm

    ...

class TrainingCreateView(EventCreateView):
    form_class = TrainingForm
```

Comment: i have tried this first, because i think its the most elegant way. but as mentioned in the comment above, i had some other problems ...

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't work for the `TrainingCreateView` because the `__init__` view does the following

1. It sets `self.form_class = TrainingForm`
2. `super(TrainingCreateView, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)` calls the `__init__` of `EventCreateView` ...
3. Which sets `self.formclass = EventForm`

You can get around this by changing the order of your `__init_` method. Note that the method doesn't have to return anything.

```
class TrainingCreateView(EventCreateView):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TrainingCreateView, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.form_class = TrainingForm
```

However, from the code you've written, it is not clear why you need to set `self.form_class` in the `__init__` method, rather than just setting it as a class attribute. If you need to set it dynamically, a better option might be to override [`get_form_class`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin.get_form_class) instead.

Comment: thanks for your answer. it worked as well, but i had a problem with my urls.py file. I just worked, after i changed "event/add/" to "event-add/" .. so i expect that the regex always returns the first string with "add" on the end.

Comment: Glad you got it working, but I'm not sure what you mean by *the regex always returns the first string with "add" on the end*. From the code you've posted, I can't see how the two regexes `r'event/event/add/$` and `r'event/training/add/$` would cause problems.